# Why is my .phtml file override not being reflected?

Tags: php, templates, overriding, magento2, magento2.2

I am new to Magento 2.2. I have tried to override the Magneto Blank Theme.phtml file, I have done the following:

**Blank Theme File Path**
/Magento-Dir/vendor/magento/module-theme/view/frontend/templates/html/title.phtml

**My File path**
app/design/frontend/MyTheme/Acorn/module-theme/template/html/title.phtml

**My File**

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

// @codingStandardsIgnoreFile

/**
 * @var $block \Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Title
 */
$cssClass = $block->getCssClass() ? ' ' . $block->getCssClass() : '';
$title = '';
if (trim($block->getPageHeading())) {
    $title = '<span class="base" data-ui-id="page-title-wrapper" ' .  $block->getAddBaseAttribute() . '>'
        . $block->escapeHtml($block->getPageHeading()) . '</span>';
}
?>
<?php if ($title): ?> <h1>Test Text</h1>
<div class="page-title-wrapper<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $cssClass ?>">
    <h1 class="page-title"
        <?php if ($block->getId()): ?> id="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getId() ?>" <?php endif; ?>
        <?php if ($block->getAddBaseAttributeAria()): ?>
            aria-labelledby="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getAddBaseAttributeAria() ?>"
        <?php endif; ?>>
        <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $title ?>
    </h1>
    <?= $block->getChildHtml() ?>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

After this, I had run the `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f` removed pub/static/frontend folder then reloaded my page. Still, it pointing the blank theme file.

I have followed this guide:
http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/frontend-dev-guide/templates/template-walkthrough.html

Answer (score 2):

Your file path is incorrect. Please override this file on the below path.

```
app/design/frontend/MyTheme/Acorn/Magento_Theme/template/html/title.phtml
```